# Nodejs custom successRedirect page after login

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport-local, passport.js

How can I make custom successRedirect page after login in node,js based on value from mysql user row? Something like that:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {

        var strQuery = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='"+username+"' and password_text='"+password+"'";
        connection.query( strQuery, function(err, users){
            if (err) { return done(err); }

            if (typeof users[0] == 'undefined' && users.length == 0) {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username or password' });
            }
            if (password != users[0].password_text ) {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
            }
            return done(null, users[0]);
        });
    }
));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done, ) {

    var strQuery = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='"+id+"'";
    connection.query( strQuery, function(err, users){
        return done(null, users[0]);
    });
});



app.post('/login',
    passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login', failureFlash: true }),
    function(req, res, next) { 
        if (req.user.userlevel > 3) {         // Here is my problem I dont't know how get userlevel value
            return res.redirect('/index1');
        } else {
            res.redirect('/index2');
        }
    });
```

I don't know why is my code not working... `userlevel` is real column in `users` table 
Thanks for any advise

Comment: please look into parameterized queries instead of concatenating your SQL string.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  If you managed to resolve this, maybe you could post the finished code as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [strategy](http://passportjs.org/guide/configure/) is what you use to authenticate the user and then send that user to the done callback. if the user you find has a userlevel property when returned then you'll be able to access it via `req.user.userlevel` like you've done.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I have updated code please take a look. I don't know what else is requied for fix this issue...

Comment: What fields are in your users table? Those should be available as properties on your user.